# Why doesn't $\vec{E} =\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int\frac{\rho \hat{r}\;dxdydz}{r^2}$ blow up at $r=0$, when $\rho$ is finite?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coordinate-systems, integration, singularities

Electric field at $(x,y,z)$ produced by a continuous distribution of charges is given by:$$\mathbf{E}(x,y,z) =\dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int\dfrac{\rho(x',y',z') \mathbf{\hat{r}} \;\mathrm{d}x'\mathrm{d}y'\mathrm{d}z'}{r^2}.$$ Now, as Edward Purcell in his book writes :

> This equation can be used to find the field at any point within the distribution. The integrand **doesn't blow up at $r=0$** because the volume element in the numerator is **in that limit proportional to $r^2 \mathrm{d} r$**. That is to say, so long as $\rho$ remains finite everywhere, even in the interior or of a charge on the boundary of a charge distribution.

Why does the equation doesn't blow up at $r=0\;?$ Why does the volume become $r^2 \mathrm{d}r$ at limit?

Answer (score 5):

In spherical coordinates, the [volume element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element) becomes
$$
dV = r^2 \sin\phi\, dr \, d\theta\, d\phi
$$
where
\begin{align}
r^2 &= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \\
\tan\theta &= \frac xy \\
\tan^2\phi  &= \frac{x^2 + y^2}{z^2}
\end{align}
If the density is uniform over a sphere of radius $R$, then the radial integral becomes
$$
\int_0^R \frac{\rho\,\hat r}{r^2} r^2 dr = \int_0^R \rho\,\hat r\,dr.
$$
The divergence in the denominator has been cancelled out by the $r^2$ in the volume element.

To complete the integral you have to observe that the unit vector $\hat r$ changes direction over the angular part of the integral; the electric field vanishes at the center of a uniformly charged sphere.
This is the integral used to prove the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) for electrostatics, which tells you that the electric field outside a uniform spherical shell of charge is the same as the field due to a point charge at the sphere's center.

Comment: +1. Ok, thanks, sir, for posting the answer but I do want to know the deduction. Can you show this?

Comment: The transformation $dx\,dy\,dz \to r^2 \sin\phi\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$ is derived in every textbook on multidimensional calculus.

Comment: Yes, I do know that very well, sir.

Comment: What if it is a surface charge distribution? Will the integral blow up?

Comment: @Kyson A surface charge distribution is represented by a [delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) in $r$, which is well-behaved.

Answer (score 2):

To understand Purcell's point, you should give a read to the first chapter of Griffiths' **Introduction to Electrodynamics**. At the end of that chapter, Griffiths deals with this very issue in some detail. The crux of his treament lies in the definition of divergence of this vector function:

$\mathbf{v}=\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$

Before I proceed with the rest of the answer, I should say this - The volume element is proportional to the $r^2dr$ in the [spherical coordinate system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html). The general volume element in the spherical coordinate system is $d\tau=r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$, where $\theta$ is the angle with the $z$ axis (which is different from the convention used in the Wolfram page that I linked above).

Since, the charge distribution is spherically symmetric, the density would depend on $r$ only. The rest of the terms amount to a factor of $4\pi$. The $r^2$ gets cancelled by the term downwards and you are safe from $r=0$.

Now, about the vector $\mathbf{v}$,

$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2\frac{1}{r^2})=0$

where the definition for the [divergence is used for the spherical coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates). The problem is when we use the divergence theorem i.e.

$\int \nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}d\tau=\oint\mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{a}$

where the $d\mathbf{a}$ is equal to the area on the surface of a sphere of radius $R$. Then, when you perform the integration, you get $\oint\mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{a}=4\pi$. So, clearly, we have a problem with the right hand and left side, since we've already seen that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}=0$. So, the divergence of the vector function $\mathbf{v}$ is one of those functions which is zero almost everywhere but have infinite contribution at one point, and thus give a finite overall contribution. What we are looking for is a dirac delta function. So define,

$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}=4\pi\delta^3(\mathbf{r})$.

By defining it this way, we have ensured that the Gauss' law holds. And this also ensures that even if the function blows up at $r=0$, the integral doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$, then the integral would be similar to ${\rho \times r^3} \over {r^2}$, or ${(\rho \times r)}$ as $r$ approaches 0.

Comment: Can you please, sir, elaborate your explanation?

Comment: If the integrand approxes to $\rho \times r$, then also it blows up at $r=0$:(

Comment: It goes to 0. Is that blowing up?