# Can magnetic field effect the charge which produce this magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A Moving charge makes magnetic field. Then a magnetic field produced by one moving charge can effect this charge which make this magnetic field??

Comment: The moving charge also has an electric field. Are you curious about magnetic self-force but not electric self-force?

Comment: @Ghoster, Yes, but is there electric self force??

Comment: When there is a self-force, such as [on an accelerating charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham–Lorentz_force), how much is electric and how much is magnetic depends on the reference frame from which one observes the charge.

Comment: the checked answer here is relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224064/do-moving-charges-get-affected-by-the-magnetic-field-they-create-while-moving-to